# Call python script with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, python

Can someone please give a short code example on how to call a python script from Javascript using JQuery and parse the result, which is a Python dict? Below what I have until now, but doesn't work.

Python code (script.py):

```
def pythonFuntion():
dict = {"val1":"this is x", "val2":True}
return json.dumps(dict)
```

Intermediate PHP (intermediate.php):

```
<?php
  exec("python script.py", $output);
  echo $output;
?>
```

Javascript:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $.ajax({
    url: 'intermediate.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
         alert(obj.val1);
    }
   });
  </script>
```

Comment: Not sure, but don't the Python functions need proper indentation?

Comment: _doesn't work_ means what exactly? Any error messages?

Comment: I can't see any logic errors. Are you sure the paths are correct?

Comment: you can visit intermediate.php directly to check if php return result. Maybe it's not jquery problem.

Comment: @OcasoProtal: I don't get any error messages, but it doesn't alert anything.If I visit my PHP directly, i get 'Array'

Comment: @elprup: if I visit my php directly, I get 'Array'.

Comment: @Juhana: yes, it does return an Array, but that's what I need, right?

Comment: Instead of `echo $output;` use `echo json_encode( $output );`

Comment: @DreamEater The output from the Python script is already JSON.

Comment: @Juhana But the jQuery is fetching data from PHP, where the OP states **if I visit my php directly, I get 'Array'**

Comment: @Juhana Now I don't get anything if I visit my PHP page, and it alerts null in Javascript (using implode as you outline below)

Comment: @DreamEater Yes, but the array is each line of the Python script output (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), not an actual data structure. For example it might be `array( '{', '"foo": "bar"', '}' )`.

Comment: @MaVe Try `print_r( $output )` instead and see what it says. (It'd be better if you commented the answer directly.)

Comment: @Juhana Then in PHP it prints `Array ( )`

Comment: @MaVe What if you run the Python script directly in the terminal? Looks like it doesn't output anything.

Comment: @Juhana Then it runs, but doesn't print anything (since it is a `return` and not a `print` )

Comment: ... ... ... that's the problem. You need to print it. You can't "return" something from Python to PHP.

Comment: @Juhana Thanks! Now I get `Array ( [0] => {"val2": true, "val1": "this is x"} ) ` How can I now parse this in Javascript?

Comment: @Juhana Ah, got it, that was your previous answer (with implode). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't `echo` an array in PHP, it just prints "Array" (as you noticed). You need something like this to print each line stored in the array:

```
exec("python script.py", $output);
echo implode( "\n", $output );
```

Also, as established in the comments, the Python script must actually output what you want to pass to PHP so that `exec()` can collect it. You can't use `return` to pass data from Python to PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Your PHP look OK. The problem may be in your javascript code. Your *obj* variable is undefined. You must alert *data.val1* instead of *obj.val1*.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $.ajax({
    url: 'intermediate.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
         alert(data.val1);
    }
   });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change python file to this:

```
import json
def pythonFuntion():
    dict = {"val1":"this is x", "val2":True};
    return json.dumps(dict);
print( pythonFuntion() );
```

Then, in the PHP; use this:

```
<?php
  exec("python script.py", $output);
  echo $output[0];
?>
```

And your jQuery will work. (Just tested it on my system).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's the success function what's wrong, change obj to data:

```
success: function(data){
     alert(data.val1);
}
```